# Use forloop counter as list index in Django template

Tags: python, django

I am passing a list `uans` as a context for my template. I want to iterate over `uans` to display values within it. My code is as follows:

```
{% for q in qlist %}

    <span>You answered: {{ uans.{{forloop.counter0}} }}</span>

{% endfor %}
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Could not parse the remainder: '{{forloop.counter0' from 'uans.{{forloop.counter0'`

It works fine if I write `uans.0` ,, `uans.1` and so on.
I want to use the forloop counter as an index.
I want to iterate over `uans`only using the counter.

Please suggest a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Someone posted about filters but the comments have been closed.This is not a duplicate of the mentioned question @Sayse

Comment: I believe it is, you're trying to do the exact same thing I was doing. If it weren't a duplicate then what you're doing doesn't make sense, how do you know the users answer will always have the same index as the question?

Comment: My `qlist` has the questions and `uans` has the option which the user answered. `qlist` is a QuerySet. `uans` just has the options as strings inside it

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a duplicate, you want something like `questions_and_answers = zip(qlist, uans)` in the view, then `{% for q, a in questions_and_answers %}` in your template.

Comment: I think i misunderstood the other question which @Sayse mentioned. I used a similar approach to that by using `zip()` and i'm getting the expected results. Thanks  :)